# Adding some fields to all tables in a databse

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add 2 fields:

```
lastUpdatedUserId
lastUpdatedTime
```

to all the table in my sql serverdatabase.

How can I easily do this?

Comment: and the datatypes are `int` and `datetime`?

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

```
Declare @Count int
Set @Count=0
Declare @Sample TABLE
(Name varchar(max),rowNum int)

Declare @sql nvarchar(max)

Insert into @Sample
SELECT TABLE_NAME ,row_number() over ( order by TABLE_NAME) as rowNum
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and TABLE_CATALOG='Your database name'

while @count<(Select max(rowNum) from @Sample)
 BEGIN
 DEclare @Table varchar(max)
 Set @Table=(Select Name from @Sample where rowNum=@Count)

 SET @sql='ALTER Table ' + @table +' Add lastUpdatedUserId int ,lastUpdatedTime   datetime'
 execute (@sql)

Set @count=@count+1
END
```

Much simpler way of doing it is

```
Declare @Sample Table
(Name nvarchar(max))
 Insert into @Sample
 Select 'ALTER TABLE dbo.' + TABLE_NAME + ' ADD lastUpdatedUserId int NULL' 
 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
 WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Now execute the statements from @Sample table

Answer (score 0):

This one line query will do, what you are trying to do.

Please modify the datatypes as per your requirement.

using sp_msforeachtable system stored procedure.

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER table ? add lastUpdatedUserId varchar(20), lastUpdatedTime datetime PRINT '? modified' "
```